# Get total Sum from SQL Query of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, powerbi, inner-join

I have two tables which are as follows:

Table1 and Table2.

Table1 :

```
Group   Id
___________
Jam     J1
Jam     J2
Jam     J3
Meyo    M1
Meyo    M2
Meyo    M3
Meyo    M4
Meyo    M5
Sauce   S1
Sauce   S2
Sauce   S3
Sauce   S4
```

Table2:

```
Id  Shops  Companies
__________________
J1    20     5
J2    50     10
J3    30     10
M1    50     10
M2    50     10
M3    20     30
M4    80     25
M5    100    25
S1    50     10
S2    50     10
S3    100    30
```

I want a SQL query which would show me the result in total manner. The Output that I want is :

```
Group  Shops  Companies
________________________
Jam     100     25
Meyo    300     100
Sauce   200     50
```

I have done it using the PowerBI and I know it can be done using SQL too but I am not able to achieve it. I have prepared the table to learn the query. Also it would be amazing if I get to know how powerBI Measure can be different from SQL query, or are they same?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how these sums are *cumulative*. Presumably, you just want aggregation and regular sums:

```
select t1.grp, sum(t2.shops) shops, sum(t2.companies) companies
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.grp
```

Note that `group` is a language keyword, hence a poor choice for a column name. I renamed it to `grp` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Group ,  sum(Shops) as shops, sum(companies) as companies
from 
Table1
join Table2
on Table1.Id = Table2.Id
group by Table1.Group
```

Comment: If you could expand on why this query solves the issue, it would be helpful to future readers to understand how this answer works so it could be applied in other situations.